# Difference between variable and print variable

Tags: python

I have the following code (Assuming I am typing in IDLE line by line)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u"My Currency is - £"
s
print s
```

for - `s` - I'm getting an output - `u'My Currency is - \xa3'`

for - `print s` - I'm getting an output - `u'My Currency is - £'`

What is the difference ? Why I am getting different outputs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, `print` shows the result of `__str__` on its arguments, which may be different from `__repr__`.  For more, see here: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Not exactly, try calling explicit `str(s)` or `s.__str__()` and You'll get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...`, but `print` works fine, so `print` makes something more.

Answer (score 0):

it is beacause of differences between

> __str__

and

> __repr__.

.
[diff. **str** and repr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)