# Why does "type()" work differently for variables and classes?

Tags: python, types, jupyter-lab

Does anyone have an explanation for the following:

[image]
I would expect the same result when running `type(mystring)` as `type(b)` or `type(bobo)` i.e. getting the class of the object, i.e. a class.

What is happening?

Here the code for copy and paste.

```
mystring='blabla'
type(mystring)
class bobo():
    pass
b=bobo()
type(b)
print(type(b))
type(bobo)
print(type(bobo))
```

To avoid misunderstandings.
the strange thing for me is that
`type(b)` does not produce the same result as `print(type(b))` and that
`type(bobo)` does not produce the same as `print(type(bobo))`

EDIT 2:

[image]

EDIT 3:
The question:
[Difference between variable and print variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309500/difference-between-variable-and-print-variable)
Does not answer my question. It refers to strings which is the part of the jupyter behaviour I understand.

In short: why type(bobo) is 'type' and not ' class '

Comment: `bobo` is the class, `b` is an instance of the class. Why would you expect `type()` to return the same thing?

Comment: If you want to know what `type(b.__class__)` is, you can run that.

Comment: That said -- please don't post code as screenshots. Run your sample in a textual Python interpreter and you'll be able to post it as a transcript. This is better for everyone for the reasons described in [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: I will add the question since it was not clear. the strange thing is that type(b) or type(bobo) does not produce the same as print(type(b)) and print(type(bobo))

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing out. I did because this is a jupyter lab thing I imagine. I pasted the code anyway for copy it, paste it and reproduce it.

Comment: @JFerro When you do `type(b)`, the REPL is printing `repr(b)`. When you do `print(type(b))`, the `print()` function prints `str(b)`. It's common for `repr()` to add more details.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I might be missing something very obvious, but as far as I know a cell printout the result of the last line WITHOUT having to use print. BUT, type(b) and print(type(b)) are not the same. Nor are the same type(bobo) and print(type(bobo))

Comment: If that's what you want to know, maybe a better title would be: *Why is print(type(...something...)) different from what type(...something...) prints on the REPL?*

Comment: (and as Barmar says, it's the difference between `str()` and `repr()` -- and that difference isn't speciifc to types; many if not most objects have some difference between the representation for those two possible ways they can be converted to strings).

Comment: f/e, `print('hello world')` and just `'hello world'` _also_ prints two different things (`hello world` and `'hello world'` respectively).

Comment: actually print('hello world') and 'hello world' produce the same result

Comment: @JFerro, not at a CPython REPL (aka the thing that running `python` or `python3` at the command line launches). If you're using some graphical thing, well, that's a question of that tool you're using, but this is tagged `python`, not `jupyter` or `ipython` or whatnot.

Comment: It used to be tagged jupyter-lab which I removed, but apparently the question has taken a different direction.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right, some editor deleted the tag. this is totally jupyter lab related. I added another pic for clarification

Comment: @JFerro, you claimed that the outputs in both cases are identical, but the #16 output in the new screenshot has no quotes -- it's just `hello world` -- but the #17 one is `'hello world'`, **with quotes**. The `repr()` vs `str()` distinction holds.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And you didn't notice that the content you added did not match the question, and even removed what the question was about (since with your output `type(b)` and `print(type(b))` are equal)?

Comment: @Barmar That is in IMO a bad dupe target, since it specifically references Python2.7 syntax. The second dupe is a lot better. Also, neither of those actually help in this case

Comment: question closed, unfortunately, since the question posted as possible answer is related, but far away. If I would have to put it ultra short: type(bobo) gives 'type' but bobo is a class.

Comment: @JFerro That's the type of all classes. Try `type(str)`

Comment: Different REPLs have slightly different ways of printing values. So Jupyter-Lab is slightly different from IPython and the built-in python REPL.